# boxsdk demo/auth.py fails on from boxsdk import OAuth2

Tags: python-3.x, box

Running on python 3.6 (anaconda)

Tried to run authenticate() within boxsdk: demo/auth.py and get error on import.

Looks like error is happening in /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boxsdk/object/events.py....

class EventsStreamType(with_metaclass(ExtendableEnumMeta, TextEnum)):

I did look thru other posts but don't see solution

1. python - Fix 'new enumerations must be created as' - Stack Overflow
2. boxsdk 1.x does not import in python 3.6.0 · Issue #195 · box/box ...

ERROR

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-e86018378e6f> in <module>()
      9 from wsgiref.simple_server import WSGIServer, WSGIRequestHandler, make_server
     10 
---> 11 from boxsdk import OAuth2
     12 
     13 

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boxsdk/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 
      5 from .auth import JWTAuth, OAuth2
----> 6 from .client import *  # pylint:disable=wildcard-import,redefined-builtin
      7 from .object import *  # pylint:disable=wildcard-import,redefined-builtin
      8 from .version import __version__

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boxsdk/client/__init__.py in <module>()
      3 from __future__ import unicode_literals, absolute_import
      4 
----> 5 from .client import Client
      6 from .developer_token_client import DeveloperTokenClient
      7 from .development_client import DevelopmentClient

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boxsdk/client/client.py in <module>()
     10 from ..object.folder import Folder
     11 from ..object.search import Search
---> 12 from ..object.events import Events
     13 from ..object.file import File
     14 from ..object.group import Group

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boxsdk/object/events.py in <module>()
     13 
     14 # pylint:disable=too-many-ancestors
---> 15 class EventsStreamType(with_metaclass(ExtendableEnumMeta, TextEnum)):
     16     """An enum of all possible values of the `stream_type` parameter for user events.
     17 

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/enum.py in __prepare__(metacls, cls, bases)
    117         enum_dict = _EnumDict()
    118         # inherit previous flags and _generate_next_value_ function
--> 119         member_type, first_enum = metacls._get_mixins_(bases)
    120         if first_enum is not None:
    121             enum_dict['_generate_next_value_'] = getattr(first_enum, '_generate_next_value_', None)

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/enum.py in _get_mixins_(bases)
    437         # base is now the last base in bases
    438         if not issubclass(base, Enum):
--> 439             raise TypeError("new enumerations must be created as "
    440                     "`ClassName([mixin_type,] enum_type)`")
    441 

TypeError: new enumerations must be created as `ClassName([mixin_type,] enum_type)`
```

Comment: Same Observation ... **BUMP**